# « Être tué à l'ennemi » : lieu par métonymie ?

Tags: sens, indications-de-lieu, figure-de-style

> A-t-on un phénomène comparable, par analogie avec *au [combat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combat)*,
>   *au [front](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/front)*, dans l'expression (*être [tué](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tu%C3%A9/1)*) ***à l'[ennemi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ennemi)***, qui est propre à ce seul nom ?

C'est la réflexion à laquelle nous convie *Le bon usage*.<sup>1</sup> On doit entendre *comparable* à un cas de *métonymie* où la désignation d'une personne est appliquée à un lieu. On donne comme exemple, entre autres, « *Les coiffeurs sont fermés le lundi* » (Cocteau, *Parents terribles*, II, 1), « senti comme peu distingué », ou *aller au coiffeur* dans la langue parlée, « généralement condamné », vu la préposition [*chez*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2018) (qualifications tirées du *LBU*).

Quelle réponse donnerait-on à la question proposée ?

---

<sub>1. MM. Grevisse et Goosse (*ed. Duculot*), au §209 (note *R1*). [Extrait](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=10218&p=18485&hilit=m%C3%A9tonymie#p18485) du contexte au *LBU*; l'appel à la note *R1* immédiatement après : « *Par métonymie, un nom désignant une personne est appliquée à un lieu.* [R1] ». Suivent un paragraphe sur le *nom de profession* (... *épiciers, encadreur, coiffeurs*, etc.) et un autre sur le *nom d'ordre religieux*. Généralement métonymie : [classification](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=60214&p=115291&hilit=m%C3%A9tonymie&sid=f9444119a34f4a45cc17f30a37d0520e#p115291), [description](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3197), exemples ([1](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13041&p=23441&hilit=m%C3%A9tonymie#p23441), [2](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27037&p=50334&hilit=m%C3%A9tonymie#p50334)).</sub>

Comment: Pour complément sur l'origine de l'expression : « « Tué à l'ennemi » est l'expression militaire utilisée en France sur les documents administratifs des soldats tués lors de la Première Guerre mondiale. Cette expression a été étendue par la suite. » (Source : [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu%C3%A9_%C3%A0_l%27ennemi))

Comment: @Chop Merci, oui ça m'a fait penser au _killed in action_ (KIA) en anglais. Je vois qu'on dit [_tué en action_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killed_in_action) sur la page en français.

Comment: «A l’ennemi» peut dire «au front» (un lieu) donc, oui, c’est comparable au «lieu par métonymie» & l’exemple de “au coiffeur”.  Mais d’après moi, c’est plus proche à «‘une partie pour le tout’ par métonymie» (synecdoque particularisante) (ou même une métaphore) où «l’ennemi» (une partie)=«la guerre» (le tout). Donc je prends «[être] tué à l’ennemi» pour dire «[être} tué à la guerre». Avec «au coiffeur», si l’on emploie “chez” (au ’lieu’ de ‘à’), ça devient «distingué» sans perdre précision du lieu; mais «chez l’ennemi», même «distingué», ne dit plus «au front», mais plutôt "behind enemy lines."

Answer (score 4):

Je crois que dans "être tué à l'ennemi" l'ennemi fait référence au moyen par lequel la personne a trouvé la mort et non pas au lieu. Ce serait dans ce sens comparable à "être tué à l'arme blanche" par exemple.

**Ajout :**

À propos du sens ultime de l'expression je viens de trouver cette explication de Michel Laval, auteur du livre "Tué à l'ennemi" :

> "Tué à l'ennemi" n'est pas tué "par" l'ennemi, mais "en allant vers...", "à la rencontre de...". Elle comporte une idée de mouvement, de défi, de provocation, quelque chose de l'insolence, de l'esprit chevaleresque et de l'"insouciance du danger" dont parlait Madame de Staël et qu'on attribuait traditionnellement au caractère français.

http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/jacques-tarnero/questions-a-michel-laval-_b_2997293.html

Answer (score 1):

"Tué à l'ennemi" semble signifier "mort aux mains de l'ennemi"; il peut donc s'agir tout autant d'un moyen (tué *par* un ennemi) ou d'un lieu (tué *en territoire* ennemi), et bien souvent une combinaison des deux (dans le cas d'un prisonnier de guerre, par exemple).