# « Aller au coiffeur » : périphrase verbale « implicite » et métonymie ?

Tags: sens, linguistique, auxiliaires, figure-de-style

**A.** Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14770) on aborde l'emploi par métonymie de la profession pour indiquer un lieu; on évoque *aller au coiffeur* pour *chez* le coiffeur, dans le sens de l'endroit où il/elle exerce le métier. Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, §209, note R2) on ajoute :

> Notez qu'on ne dit pas *je vais dîner* au *coiffeur*, car il ne s'agit
>   pas alors du salon de coiffure. On ne dit pas non plus : *je vais* à
>   *un coiffeur*, à *mon coiffeur*.

---

**B.** Par ailleurs, certains verbes peuvent être utilisés comme [*semi-auxiliaires*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_semi-auxiliaire) et se comportent alors de manière particulière en termes de sens quand ils sont ainsi conjugués et employés avec un infinitif (le participe présent est aussi possible; *aller saluant*) qui n'est pas complément. En particulier, le sème de déplacement du verbe *aller* est altéré ou sinon dissout (*je vais manger* ; comparer avec *je vais aller manger*), glissant vers l'idée de proximité temporelle, rendue par la fonction grammaticale du *futur proche*.

Cet emploi semi-auxiliaire génère une *périphrase verbale* : généralement un outil permettant de faire ressortir certaines caractéristiques propres à une réalité qu'il est parfois difficile de rendre autrement ou simplement. Pour l'[identifier](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00872100/document), un des principaux [critères](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/igram_0222-9838_1988_num_38_1_2039) est que l'infinitif dont on a traité ne doit [*pas*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_semi-auxiliaire#Distinction_entre_semi-auxiliaires_et_verbes_suivis_d.27un_infinitif_compl.C3.A9ment_d.27objet) pouvoir être pronominalisé (ils veulent déménager; ils *le* veulent). La périphrase semble être un vecteur de [grammaticalisation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalisation). Certaines constructions verbales peuvent avoir des fonctions plus ou moins comparables à celles de la périphrase.

---

Réflexions : **A' ∩ B | A' ∪ B | A', B | ?**

> (1) Je vais (aller) chez le/au coiffeur.
>  (2) Je dois aller chez le/au coiffeur.
>  (3) Il faut que j'aille me faire couper les cheveux.

- Le sens relié à la *vocation* très usuelle d'un endroit vers lequel
  on se dirige est-il en compétition avec celui du *lieu ponctuel* ou
  du *déplacement* vers celui-ci ?
- Le lexique associé au complément (au coiffeur → au salon de coiffure
  → où on se fait couper les cheveux...) a-t-il une incidence sur le
  sens d'*aller* (1) ou de *devoir aller* (2) indépendamment de l'idée
  de semi-auxiliaire ?
- Dans ce deuxième exemple, est-ce une forme d'emploi [factitif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factitif) et
  de métaphore pour rendre l'équivalent de (3) ; est-ce que ça
  s'analyse comme *devoir y aller* ou *devoir (se le faire) faire* ?
- Sans contexte (je n'ai pas de cheveux ; j'y suis allé hier ; ça fait
  3 ans que je ne me suis pas fait couper les cheveux) peut-on affirmer
  qu'il existe une différence de sens entre (2) et (3) ?
- Y a-t-il un lien à faire entre la périphrase prépositionnelle *en
  train de*, et la phase du procès de l'action d'*aller au coiffeur*
  (emploi non semi-auxiliaire) au moment de l'énoncé (en d'autres
  termes, *aller chez le coiffeur*, est-ce concevable en tant que phase
  très préliminaire de l'action d'*être en train de se faire couper les
  cheveux* et quel serait l'impact d'une telle qualification, est-ce vers quoi l'usage tend) ?

---

**Q.** Pourquoi la métonymie ne s'étendrait-elle pas à l'activité usuelle du lieu (comme on étend la profession au lieu où elle s'exerce) avec le verbe *aller* et quelle est l'interaction d'un tel complément avec l'emploi semi-auxiliaire des verbes ; le prototype *aller au/chez le coiffeur* constitue-t-il une périphrase verbale « implicite » signifiant *aller se faire couper les cheveux* ? Pourquoi, pourquoi pas ?

Comment: Please pardon my need for clarification (especially if I’m way off base), but are you saying that (and ultimately asking if): 1) “aller au coiffeur” really just means “se faire couper les cheveux” and 2) that(if) using “au” instead of “chez le” would not work with other reasons for “going to the barber,” e.g., “aller au coiffeur **uniquement** pour … /[… voir les amis]/[… avoir des conseils]/[… connaitre les heures d’ouverture/etc”?  (to be continued)

Comment: If my above "interpretation" of your question is even close (especially my item #1), does/would this mean: 1) that “aller au coiffeur [pour] se faire couper les  cheveux” would be totally redundant and 2) that (since “aller au coiffeur” means “getting a haircut”) I could say “je vais aller au coiffeur/à la coiffeuse" even if my wife (who’s not a barber/hairstylist) was going to be cutting/trimming my hair in the rec room?

Answer (score 1):

*Pour le paragraphe « Réflexions : ... »*

Les exemples sans contexte sont stériles, car ils cherchent à instrumentaliser, à mathématiser avec un jargon de haut niveau, la vie courante, ses usages aux mœurs volages, et ses expressions poétiques fortement imagées.

On m’a toujours demandé d’*aller chez le coiffeur*, on ajoutait « On mène la bique au cab<sup>1</sup> et on va chez le coiffeur ! », quoi qu’aient pu déclarer les hautes autorités.

Pour la coiffure on supprimait toujours les « /ou » des exemples, et pour ce qui des puces :

1. Pour qu’il  y ait *compétition*, il faudrait savoir sur quel stade elle a lieu, sinon revoir Voltaire et son ironie sur les effets et les causes.
2. Aller chez le coiffeur pour se faire couper les cheveux, pour les mettre en plis (bien frisés surtout), pour les teindre, pour lui acheter un produit de qualité professionnelle, pour prendre un rendez-vous, parce qu’on a pris un rendez-vous, pour saluer son beau-frère, pour avoir la même coupe que Toto, en même temps que son frère et avec maman…
   Là est l’*incidence*, à vous de mettre le *doit* à bon escient.
3. *factitif* est un mot surréaliste, puisque *je* coupe les cheveux de personne.
4. *Sans contexte*, pour une fois oui, car le 2 ci-dessus indique que l’on ne vas pas  chez le coiffeur que pour se faire tondre, il faut alors revenir à l'*intention* de l'auteur.
5. À vous de revoir la question : si *je suis en train de me faire couper les cheveux*, je suis déjà assis sur le fauteuil, et donc je suis chez le coiffeur, et donc *pas en train d’y aller*.

Normalement le gras Q. devrait trouver réponse ci-avant.

Métonymie semble indiquer que quelque chose a bougé dans les règles dès que l’on s’approche d’un lieu, mais si l’on s’approche d’un lieu, c’est pour quoi y faire : *quel usage, quel contexte, quelle intention* ?

---

<sup>1 - On amène la chèvre au bouc.</sup>